# Tor : 2 connections at the same time

Tags: anonymity

Sometimes I´ve got 2 TCP connections to Tor nodes (entry points), one is the 'main' that is used always when i run something through
Tor (iceweasel...) ,the other connection exchanges a few TCP packets every few minutes .

The odd thing to me is that the second connection sometimes is established at the beginning when i start tor, sometimes it takes 10, 20 minutes later or
doesn´t establish the connection at all.

Does anyone know why is it for ? What kind of data is being transferred ?

pst: tor+proxychains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second connection is the node you are hosting in the network. There is only small amount of data transfers, because there is an enormous amount of nodes in the tor network (every user is a node). You are basically giving some of your bandwith to the whole network (small amount) and in return, you are allowed to use the network and increase anonimity.

Comment: By default, you don't run a node yourself.

Comment: @user10008 You are right, you can opt off. However, many people would rather optin because it increases relative anonimity. OP's question about a 2nd TCP connection is due to his sharing of his bandwith with the Tor network.

Answer (score 0):

You might already know how Tor works, you start it, and it uses multiple other users as relay to "mask" you.

This is excactly what the 2nd connection is, you are also a relay for others when using it (depending on your settings), so others can use you as a relay too.

The amount of bandwidth you "donate" to the network while being online can be configured in Tor's settings, along with if you want to be a part with it yes or no.